# File written by NodeJS gives 404 when served from web server

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm writing a file with NodeJS into a subdirectory of my public_html directory.

I know the directory exists and the file exists as I can view it on FTP and download and view it's contents, but when I try to access it in the browser I get 404. I can upload files into that directory via FTP and view them in the browser with no issues.

File permissions are 644, it's just a static JSON file. It's written with the 'fs' module and I receive no errors when writing the file.

Any help would be great.

```
fs.writeFile(dir + "/" + matchId + '.json', JSON.stringify(lineup), function(err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log("File written:", dir + "/" + matchId + '.json');
});
```

Comment: What are the subdirectory permissions ?

Comment: I can only write the file if the sub directory is 777, but I feel like that shouldn't be the case

Comment: Can you should the code you use to create the file ?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the OP

Comment: Do you see the file created in that directory using ftp ? It could be created at another location using the same directory name.

Comment: Have you checked the paths? Might be an issue with absolute and relative paths... had something similar in the past, but just can't remember it.

Comment: Yes it is definitely in the correct directory, I've uploaded a JSON file via FTP and I can view that in the browser. I can't view the file created by the Node app, even thought both contain the exact same data

Comment: Try deleting all files from your directory. Upload the JSON file via HTTP and then access via FTP - does it show up where you expect? It really sounds like you might be uploading to a different directory than you're serving from.

Comment: It's definitely being written to the correct directory. I've written the JSON file via Node, then uploaded one via FTP to the same directory (I can see the node file in the FTP client) and I can view the FTP-uploaded file fine. They're both in the same directory

Comment: Can you show the code which reads the file, url format,  how you are inputting the file name to read (I.e. sending the file name via request)?

Comment: @notionquest I'm not uploading the file, it's created from XML data converted to JSON by the NodeJS application, and then written into a subdirectory of public_html on the same server. I am able to download the file via FTP and view it locally. I feel like it's some sort of permission/group issue between NodeJS and the NGINX server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the issue was file ownership. I was running the NodeJS application under a different user than the Nginx web server. I moved the NodeJS app over so they were under the same user and now it works.

Note - Initially I tried adding the user running the NodeJS app to the same group as the web server but that didn't work, even though file permissions were 664. If someone has a solution for that, it would be a great help.